# Easiest way to control of on-stage mix with in-ear monitors?

Tags: mixing, mixer, live-sound

I'm a keyboard player with two boards I typically patch out to DI boxes at venues.  I've been using on-stage amps but want to move to in-ear monitors.

The challenge I want to solve is getting the venue's board mix into something I can control on stage that goes into IEMs.

Looking at the [Behringer 2/2 mixers](https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0A0H), they, unfortunately, can't post to both buses

I was hopeful of doing something like this here:

- Line 1: Monitor feed from the venue's board
- Line 2: Keyboard 1 (mono)
- Line 3: Keyboard 2 (L)
- Line 4: Keyboard 2 (R)

Then on the bus side:

- Line 1 + Line 2 + Line 3 + Line 4 ⇾ IEM
- Line 2 + Line 3 + Line 4 ⇾ Main

The Main bus would go out to the DI boxes.

Unfortunately, the Behringer box is 'one bus or the other'; if you split to the alt bus, it's muted in the mains.

Is there a way to achieve something like this or better?  If I can find a mixer that can allow me to not feed the board back to itself and support the IEMs, I'd be in good shape!

Thanks for your advice.